# How to access the chid class data member from parent class in c++

Tags: class, inheritance

i want to access the data member in child class from the base class. i dont know it is possible or not. if possible please tell me how to do that.

```
class a {

void sample(){

//i want to use the ptr value here

}

}

class b: public a{

int *ptr;

b(int *_ptr){ptr=_ptr;}

}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if somebody just creates an `a` directly? In that case, there is no `b` and therefore no `ptr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code as you have it, it is not possible.

The best way to get what you want is probably to make `ptr` a `protected` member of class `a`, so that it is accessible to all classes that inherit from `a` (like `b`)

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of [Circular dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). You may want to consider moving `ptr` to the base class.